# ERROR - Cannot infer instance

Tags: haskell, types, instance, type-inference

I am a beginner in Haskell. I have this function

```
test f xs 
  | length xs == 0  = []
  | f (head xs)     = head xs : test f (tail xs)
  | otherwise       = test f (tail xs)
```

This function should make a list from every element of the list xs which is matching the f value but it gives back an error:

```
test 1 [1,2]
ERROR - Cannot infer instance
*** Instance   : Num (a -> Bool)
*** Expression : test 1 [1,2]
```

This part:

```
| f (head xs)
```

should be a Bool but is it? Is it working as a filter? How can I make this function work? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: As a general suggestion, in Haskell you should prefer pattern matching to any use of `length,head,tail`. Especially `head,tail` should be avoided as much as possible, since they are partial -- they will crash your program on a wrong input. (Exhaustive) pattern matching has no such issue. I'd also recommend using `-Wall` to report warnings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Always use type signatures

Evidently, `f` is a kind of predicate: you apply it to values in the list, and it yields a boolean value. So the type of `test` is

```
test :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
```

BTW the standard name for this is [`filter`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:filter).

If you're not sure about the signature yourself, you can actually ask GHCi

```
> :t test
test :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
```

...but I strongly recommend to instead *start* with the signature: first think about what you want your function to accomplish, then worry about the implementation.

Anyway, so to test the `test` function, you need to give it an `(a -> Bool)` function and a list. Is `1` a function? I daresay not<sup>†</sup>, therefore `test 1 [1,2]` can't make sense. You probably mean something like `test (\x -> x==1) [1,2]`, which can also be written simply `test (==1) [1,2]`.

A couple of remarks on your code:

- You're using guards to check if a list is empty. First of all, to just check if a list is empty, *never* evaluate its `length` – this needs to traverse the entire list. You *could* use the [`null`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:null) function, which does just that – check if a container is empty ...
- ... but that still leaves the problem of actually taking a value out of the list. You can indeed take the first value of a nonempty list with `head`, but this is only safe in a branch where you've first *checked* that it's nonempty. This is easy to get wrong. A much better solution is to just *pattern match* on the list head: instead of

  ```
  test f xs 
    | length xs == 0  = []
    | f (head xs)     = ...
  ```

  write

  ```
  test f [] = []
  test f (x:xs)
    | f x   = ...
  ```

  This way, you *can't* mistakenly evaluate the head of an empty list, because the compiler ensures that `x` is only in scope in a clause that has been checked to be nonempty.

Look at [the source code](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/src/GHC.List.html#filter) of the standard `filter` function for final reference.

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>Actually, `1` *can* be a function... number literals are overloaded in Haskell; you could theoretically write</sub>

```
instance Num (Integer -> Bool) where
  fromInteger n x = x == n
```

<sub>and then you can define `f = 1 :: Integer -> Bool`, and use it for `test` too. But... this would be a really bad idea; such instances make for very confusing code.</sub>

Comment: That's a comprehensive answer. I will read more about filters. I also understand that I must use the null function to check whether the list is empty. I'll remember that, I have tried out ` null xs  = []` and its working.

Comment: Yes, except as I said it's better not to use a separate length-check at all: with a pattern match you combine length-checking and element-extraction to one operation.

Comment: Ok, I'll remember that too. By the way, Haskell is only part of my study (master Computer Science) so sometimes it's more interesting to study all kind of constructions.